# How can I connect two windows in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying make window with chat, and "main" window. If I click at username in chat window, it should show profile in main window. What's the best way to do something like this?

Comment: `connect(someButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), someWindow, SLOT(show()));`

Comment: @mcjulcz 44 please provide some attempts, there are zillions way to do such things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass pointer to one window class from another and connect them by slots/signals:

```
class MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    public slots:
    void onUsernameSelected(...);
};


class ChatWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    MainWindow *mainWindow;

    ...

    ChatWindow(QObject *parent, MainWindow *mainWindow):
    ...
    mainWindow(mainWindow)
    {
        connect(this, &ChatWindow::usernameSelected, mainWindow, &MainWindow::onUsernameSelected);
    }
};
```